# почему не получается найти файл в idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, io

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main{ //имя класса должно быть Main
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException{
        new Main().run();
    }
    PrintWriter pw;
    Scanner sc;
    public void run() throws IOException{
        sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\IdeaProjects\\untitled6\\src\\input.txt"));
        int a=sc.nextInt(), b=sc.nextInt();
        pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\IdeaProjects\\untitled6\\src\\output.txt"));
        pw.print(a+b);
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

ошибки:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\191.7141.44\lib\idea_rt.jar=52264:C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\191.7141.44\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Lenovo\IdeaProjects\untitled6\out\production\untitled6 Main
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Lenovo\IdeaProjects\untitled6\src\input.txt (Не удается найти указанный файл)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
    at Main.run(Main.java:11)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

скриншоты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Так как я создал `input` и `output` внутри `idea`, он не присвоил им расширение `txt`.

Я нашел эти файлы в папках и открыл через блокнот. Присвоил соответствующие расширения и все заработало.